# gitignore directory pattern ignores folder with same suffix, but I want to include it

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following directory structure:

```
src/
out/
cout/
...
```

and I want to ignore `out/` but not `cout/`.

I've tried putting `^out/`, but that doesn't seem to work.  I've also tried `out/` but that also ignores `cout/`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Posted by the asker as an answer. "Sorry guys, my mistake! The cout directory was empty and, therefore, not showing up under git status. Just adding `out/` works fine and doesn't ignore `cout/`."

Answer (score 46):

Exclamation mark(!) should precede a match which should not be ignored.

The `.gitignore` file should look like:

```
out/
!cout/
```

Answer (score 14):

Sorry guys, my mistake!  The `cout` directory was empty and, therefore, not showing up under `git status`.

Just adding `out/` works fine and doesn't ignore `cout/`.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

Which version of git are you using?

With msysgit 1.6.3-preview20090507-2, the simple

```
out/
```

works for me.  cout/ is still added to the repository.