# is there anything like .gitonlytrackfiles?

Tags: git

hello is there anything like `.gitignore` but with the opposite of it?

the problem is i always add files like `git add file1.png` `git add file2.php`, and so on.

something like `.gittrack` would greatly help

```
file1.png
file2.php
folder/etc.etc
```

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985890/gitignore-directory-pattern

Comment: so can we use *; !file.php; ? in the first line ignore everything?

Comment: Sure! That's how it works. ! means exception.

Comment: thanks! sorry duplicate, didn't see that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by creating a `.gitignore` file that, by default, ignores all files (using the wildcard `*` character), but contains exceptions for paths that you do want to track (using the exception `!` character). For example, in `.gitignore` you might have:

```
*
!file1.png
!file2.png
!folder/etc.etc
```

Comment: This is the whitelist approach